# How to check if the pipe is opend before writing?

Tags: c, linux, pipe

If I write a message to a closed pipe then my program crash

```
if (write(pipe, msg, strlen(msg)) == -1) {
    printf("Error occured when trying to write to the pipe\n");
}
```

how to check if `pipe` is still opened before I writing to it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The correct way is to test the return code of `write` and then also check `errno`:

```
if (write(pipe, msg, strlen(msg)) == -1) {
    if (errno == EPIPE) {
        /* Closed pipe. */
    }
}
```

But wait: writing to a closed pipe no only returns -1 with `errno=EPIPE`, it also sends a `SIGPIPE` signal which terminates your process:

> EPIPE  fd  is  connected  to  a  pipe  or socket whose reading end is
>   closed.  When this happens the writing process will also receive a
>   SIGPIPE signal.

So before that testing works you also need to **ignore `SIGPIPE`**:

```
if (signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN) == SIG_ERR)
    perror("signal");
```