# Detecting closed unix pipe from a C program

Tags: c, pipe

I am writing a program (A) whos output is meant to be piped to another program (B). I want A to handle an error if B doesn't read all of A's data.

For simplicity I've removed unneeded code from the following example.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);

    FILE *file = fopen("test.txt" , "r");

    if (!file)
        ... Error handling ...

    int next;
    while ((next = fgetc(file)) != EOF)
        if (fputc(next, stdout) < 0 || fflush(stdout) != 0)
            ... print error message to stderr ...
}
```

This program compiles fine but it works intermitantly. I initially thought it was because of some kind of buffering in stdout that's why I added the flush.

I know this probably isn't the best way to do this but it's just for a side project. Is there a way to turn off buffering? Should I use some other transfer method instead? I've seen someone using mkfifo while I was looking around for solutions.

Edit: My issue isn't checking to see if stdout is closed. It is removing the buffer so pipes behave as expected.

Comment: _[This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19020926/645128)_ I think addresses your problem.  Be sure to read all the way to the last statement.

Comment: You can use [`setbuf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setbuf.html) or (better) 
[`setvbuf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setvbuf.html) to control buffering on newly opened files (or the pipe, or `stdout` as long as it is the first thing you do to or with `stdout`).  Flushing per character is expensive.  You'd do better to use the `write()` system call.  It will return an error (`-1`) and set `errno` to `EPIPE` if you write to a broken pipe.  Then you can write multiple characters at a time, rather than needing to one at a time.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I attempted to do that and I'm still stuck with intermittent errors. It sometimes works and other times does not.

Comment: @ryyker by looking at the code example I initially posted you can see that is not my issue. My issue is with BUFFERING, NOT with seeing if the pipe is empty. I apply the main fix in my code from that post already. If you look at the `signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);` from my code you will see that.

Comment: Guess I was going off of your title: _Detecting closed unix pipe from a C program_.  In any case, you don't need to YELL.  I can read fine without caps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two variants of your code, converted into full working programs.  The bare-bones version is `cp41.c`:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static inline void putch(char c)
{
    if (write(STDOUT_FILENO, &c, sizeof(c)) != sizeof(c))
    {
        int errnum = errno;
        fprintf(stderr, "Attempt to write '%c' failed (%d: %s)\n", c, errnum, strerror(errnum));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);

    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        putch(c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The more ornate version is `cp43.c`.  You can find the code for `stderr.h` and `stderr.c` at GitHub under https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/libsoq.  I use it because it makes reporting errors easier (single line function calls instead of multiple lines).  I could use `err_syserr()` in the `putch()` function but don't for consistency between the bare-bones and ornate versions.

```
#include "stderr.h"
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static inline void putch(char c)
{
    if (write(STDOUT_FILENO, &c, sizeof(c)) != sizeof(c))
    {
        int errnum = errno;
        fprintf(stderr, "Attempt to write '%c' failed (%d: %s)\n", c, errnum, strerror(errnum));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

static const char usestr[] = "[-l logfile] [-e]";

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    err_setarg0(argv[0]);
    signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);
    const char *filename = NULL;
    int to_stderr = 0;

    int opt;
    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "l:e")) != -1)
    {
        switch (opt)
        {
        case 'l':
            filename = optarg;
            break;
        case 'e':
            to_stderr = 1;
            break;
        default:
            err_usage(usestr);
            /*NOTREACHED*/
        }
    }

    if (optind != argc)
        err_usage(usestr);

    FILE *fp = NULL;
    if (filename != NULL)
        fp = fopen(filename, "w");

    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if (fp)
            putc(c, fp);
        if (to_stderr)
            putc(c, stderr);
        putch(c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This allows the user to copy what's being processed from standard input to standard error and/or to a log file.  This turns out to be useful.

The barebones code turns out to be 'unreliable'.  For example:

```
$ cp41 < cp41.c | sed 1q
#include <errno.h>
$
```

However, give it enough input and it becomes reliable:

```
$ cp41 < <(cat cp41.c cp41.c cp41.c) | sed 1q
#include <errno.h>
Attempt to write 'n' failed (32: Broken pipe)
$
```

The reason becomes clearer when using `cp43`:

```
$ ./cp43 <cp43.c | sed 3q
#include "stderr.h"
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>
Attempt to write 'e' failed (32: Broken pipe)
$
```

With the `-e` option:

```
$ ./cp43 -e <cp43.c | sed 3q
#include "stderr.h"
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>
#in#include "stderr.h"
cl#include <errno.h>
u#include <signal.h>
de <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static inline void putch(char c)
{
    if (write(STDOUT_FILENO, &c, sizeof(c)) != sizeof(c))
    {
        int erAttempt to write 'r' failed (32: Broken pipe)
$
```

Or with the `-l cp43.log` options:

```
$ ./cp43 -l cp43.log <cp43.c | sed 3q
#include "stderr.h"
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>
Attempt to write ' ' failed (32: Broken pipe)
$ cat cp43.log
#include "stderr.h"
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static inline void putch(char c)
{
    if (write(STDOUT_FILENO, &c, sizeof(c)) != sizeof(c))
    {
        int errnum = errno;
        fprintf(stderr, "Attempt to write '%c' failed (%d: %s)\n", c, errnum, strerror(errnum));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

static const char usestr[] = "[-l logfile] [-e]";

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    err_setarg0(argv[0]);
    signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);
    const char *filename = NULL;
    int to_stderr = $
```

Notice how much material had been written to the log ahead of what the `sed 3q` command had read.  The final `$` prompt is at the end of a partial line from the log file.

The trouble is that if the writing program gets far enough ahead of `sed 3q`, it may have finished reading and writing before `sed` terminates, so it never gets the SIGPIPE signal because, as it writes, the pipe never has 'no reader'.

You can precipitate the problem by using a different program instead of `sed`.  For example:

```
$ cp41 < cp41.c | echo

Attempt to write '#' failed (32: Broken pipe)
$
```

Answer (score 0):

`fgetc()` and `fputc()` are buffered, use `read()` and `write()` systems calls, to have unbuffered I/O.

Comment: Good suggestion, but how does this address the question about detecting closed pipes?

Comment: well you wrote in your question that the "program works intermittently", and I gave solution to that, because its not recommended to use fgetc() fputc() in first place. I'm sorry, but its not exactly obvious from the question that you are asking how to detect if pipe is closed

Comment: @Pbd I'm not ryyker but I am still having a similar issue as before even when using read() and write()

Comment: I think you need to put a bit more code,

SIGPIPE is raised if other end is closed and you try to write to it, similarly, if writing end is closed, then read gets an EOF

Probably, you can install a signal handler in A if that is the writing end and delivery of SIGPIPE will indicate reading end in B is closed, similarly, if A is reading end, then reading EOF will indicate writing end from B is closed.

Comment: @Pdb A is the writing end, B is the reading end. When B exits A does not finish writing nor does it detect it's finished. The post here has been made because the the SIGPIPE never happens. I did attach a signal handler to SIGPIPE as well and I had the same issue. SIGPIPE sometimes executed and sometimes did not. When it did execute/EOF on write happened I got incorrect information. The information printed was from after where B would have exited. That is why I mentioned a chaching issue. I'm fairly sure this is not SIGPIPE but is instead a caching issue.